# Expectation of weighted binomial distribution with weighted values

Tags: probability, combinatorics, approximation

- I flip $N$ coins.
- The $n^{th}$ coin flip has probability $p_n$ to be head.
- If the $n^{th}$ coin flip is head, I add $c_n$ to the total sum S.

How to calculate/approximate the expectation of $S$ quickly? Is it possible to simplify the following?

The number of coin flip is about 10.

Let $\vec{c} = (c_1, c_2, ..., c_N)$

Let $\vec{a} = (a_1, a_2, ..., a_N)$ be the result of the coin flips.

$a_n$ is 1 if the $n^{th}$ coin flip is head and is 0 otherwise.

The expectation is:

$E\lbrace S \rbrace =  \sum_{a_{1}, ... a_{n}}  \vec{c} \cdot \vec{a} \prod_{n = 1}^{N} a_n p_n + (1 - a_n)(1 - p_n) $

But that involves enumerating all cases of $\vec{a}$, which is not quite practical for my case because I need to calculate this for many times.

The $p_n$ are different for different coins.

Comment: small n. can't use central limit theorem: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89254/clt-can-be-used-for-weighted-sum-of-different-bernoulli-variables?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: monte carlo for sum of weighted binomial (not the expectation): https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/270227/what-is-the-cdf-of-the-sum-of-weighted-bernoulli-random-variables

Comment: Flipping many coins/Monte carlo are probably slow.

Comment: Why isn't it simply $\Sigma p_i c_i$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [linearity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity), the expected value of the sum is

$$
\mathsf E[S]=\mathsf E\left[\vec c\cdot\vec a\right]=\vec c\cdot\mathsf E\left[\vec a\right]=\vec c\cdot\vec p\;.
$$

Comment: duh. I feel dumb. Let me check again to see if this fit into the whole thing. Thanks.